# Cakephp two forms (sending data to different controller)

Tags: php, cakephp

**EDIT**
First form that needs to send data to a specific controller is here

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Message', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'messages', 'action' => 'send')
    )); 

    echo $this->Form->input('mob_network', array(
        'options' => array($list)
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input('mob_phone', array(
            'type' => 'text')); 

    echo $this->Form->input('message', array(
            'type' => 'textarea')); 


    echo $this->Form->submit('Send', array('div' => false,'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-add'));  
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

controller is here

```
class MessagesController extends AppController {
    public function send()
    {

       pr($this->request->data);

    }    
}
```

The problem is that i cant see this data. after clicking submit button the page acts as if it was refreshed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:

```
echo $this->Form->end();
```

to the end of both forms. Or you left that out in your code?

Comment: Omg i forgot that i still have to do that even if i have $this->Form->submit... TY, but the main problem is passing data from the first form to a different controller, everything else is plan B :)

Comment: I just tested something like you are doing, two forms on one view file, with diff controllers and actions, and it works. Is your problem  still there with closed forms?

Comment: My only problem now is sending data to a different controller. I have edited main question, if you could take a look :)

Comment: Uh im so stupid. It didnt work because i didnt put $this->Auth->allow paramaters for guest in that controller.. and i got no errors. half day wasted for nothing..

Comment: Well you didn't say you are using Auth component :)